# Sigle-column or multi-column index(-es)?

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I have a table with 3 columns: "Id", "A", "B". 
All of them are searchable. Id is identity and used only to search exact rows so it's clear. But I have doubts about "A" and "B". I have a 3 cases to search in my application: search by "A", search by "B" and search by "A" and "B" simultaneously. So i'm not sure which index type to choose. Should I use two single-column indexes or one multi-column? Or maybe it's better to combine single-column indexes with multi-column (3 indexes in total)? I don't really care about INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE duration, my target priority is to make SELECT as fast as possible. 
I use SQL Server 2017. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think two additional indexes will be enough:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_YourTable_AB ON YourTable(A,B) -- the first column here which has more different values
CREATE INDEX IDX_YourTable_B ON YourTable(B)INCLUDE(A)
```

If you have other columns in this table you can create included indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_YourTable_AB ON YourTable(A,B) INCLUDE(C,D,E,...)
CREATE INDEX IDX_YourTable_B ON YourTable(B) INCLUDE(A,C,D,E,...)
```

Index `IDX_YourTable_AB` might used for conditions `WHERE A='...'` or `WHERE A='...' AND B='...'` or `WHERE A LIKE '...%' AND B='...'` - used only `A` column or `A`&`B` columns.

Index `IDX_YourTable_B` might used for conditions with `B` column only (`WHERE B='...'` or `WHERE B LIKE '...%'`).

Also try to test `CREATE INDEX IDX_YourTable_BA ON YourTable(B,A)` instead of `CREATE INDEX IDX_YourTable_B ON YourTable(B)INCLUDE(A)`. Maybe it will be better.